# Обновление порядкового номера при удалении элемента jquery

Tags: jquery

Есть таблица, у каждой строки которой есть порядковый номер, этот номер нужно обновлять при удалении любого элемента:

Таблица

```
<table id="orders"> //<th> и остальные теги не вывожу
  <tr rel="<?=$orderId;?>">/* $orderId НЕ порядковый номер строки */
       <td><span class="counter">$i++</span></td>
  /* $i - выводит порядковый номер строки, который после 
  изменяется с помощью jquery function updateCounter() */
       <td class="delete">удалить</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  ...
</table>
```

Удаляю ряд с помощью jquery:

```
$(".delete").on('click', function () {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    deleteOrder(tr);
});

function deleteOrder(tr) {
    var id = tr.attr('rel');
    $.post (
        '/blog/admin/ajax/deleteOrder.php',
        {"id" : id},
        function( data ){
            tr.fadeOut();
        });
    updateCounter();
}

function updateCounter() {
    var tr = $('#orders tr');
    var i = 0;
    $.each(tr, function () {
        i++;
        $(this).find('.counter').text(i);
    });
}
```

Вся проблема в функции `updateCounter()`. При удалении строки функция не заменяет порядковый номер на новый, но если вставить другое значение, например:

```
$(this).find('.counter').text(value);
```

То все порядковые номера заменятся на `value`, будь это строка или что либо еще.

Прошу подсказать куда копать?

Проблема в селекторе? Возможно, выделяются все строки с классом `counter` и в них кладется одно и то же число, именно поэтому нет смысла в моем обновлении и

```
text(i);  ??
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что fadeOut не удаляет tr, а выкручивает ему opacity в 0.
После fadeOut вам надо еще удалить саму строку, и тогда счетчик должен нормально заработать.

Comment: Ну либо воспользоваться каким-нибудь `:visible` в селекторе строк

Comment: Еще надо вызов `updateCounter()` поместить в функцию обратного вызова `$.post()`

Comment: @Dmitry, зачем именно в  функцию обратного вызова?

Comment: @Darth, после fadeOut добавил tr.remove(), и поменял строки text(i) и i++ местами, все заработало, спасибо большое! Но я так и не понимаю почему.